'in practice' for support of a random variable
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space.
Based on

Discrete Random Variables May Have Uncountable Images
Understanding definition of a continuous random variable
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#In_probability_and_measure_theory
Is this a typo in the definition of support of a random variable?

( I'm trying to not use words like 'open' and 'closed' to reduce as much measure theory & topology as possible. )
About the 'in practice' part.
Q1
If $X$ is discrete with probability distribution function $f_X$, then are the following definitions of support $\text{supp}(X)$ the same?

$\{x \in \mathbb R | f_X(x) > 0\}$, where $f_X(x) = P(X=x)$
Smallest $R_X$ with $P(X \in R_X)=1$
Smallest closed $R_X$ with $P(X \in R_X)=1$

Q2
If $X$ is continuous with probability distribution function $f_X$, then are the following definitions of support $\text{supp}(X)$ the same?

$\{x \in \mathbb R | f_X(x) > 0\}$
Smallest $R_X$ with $P(X \in R_X)=1$
Smallest closed $R_X$ with $P(X \in R_X)=1$


What do you think?

from your Wikipedia link "In probability theory, the support of a probability distribution can be loosely thought of as the closure of the set of possible values of a random variable having that distribution."

For the continuous case, the pdf is not unique. You can pick an single $x_0$ with $f(x_0)>0$ and set it to $f(x_0)=0$. The distribution remains unchanged. So term "closed" cannot be formally dropped. But "in practice", it doesn't matter, because we don't care any null set with probability zero that never changes probability statements.

Also, "in practice", I don't think we care about the support of a random variable; the support of the distribution is of practical interest.

@ZackFisher Defining random variables in terms of support, not image

@ZackFisher well in this case 'support of $X$' refers to 'support of $f_X$' (if any such $f_X$ exists) ?

For Q1, 2 and 3 seem not equivalent in general. We can define a pmf $p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ only by choosing an enumeration of the rationals $(q_n)_n$ and setting $p(q_n)=2^{-n}$. Then the smallest set with probability one is $\mathbb{Q}$ but the smallest closed set with probability one would be $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$.
